# Two title tags in my header

Tags: title, wp-head

I'm building a child theme and it currently has a very simple `<head>` section in header.php:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
  <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
  <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

I'm guessing `wp_head()` is responsible for the second `<title>` element (it appears just there in the final HTML), but other things I've read say this is impossible.

Should I be removing the `<title>` from my header.php, or should I be adding something to my functions to remove the title from `wp_head()` (eg. `remove_action('wp_head', 'title'`) ?

Or should I be doing something else altogether?

Comment: I just noticed that this issue also occurs in the original (parent) theme. Huh!

Comment: Are you using Wordpress 4.1 and a theme that is written for 4.1. If so, then you should have this line somewhere in functions.php, `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );`. This should explain the two title tags. This feature was introduced in 4.1 and automatically add the `wp_title()` tag in the header. If so, simply copy your parent theme header.php to your child theme and delete the `wp_title()` tag in the header.php

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked. Enjoy

Comment: @PieterGoosen I think your comment should be made into an answer ;-)

Comment: @birgire done, thanks for the suggestion. Also extended a little bit :-)

Comment: great, I'm sure it will be helpful since this seems to be a common problem. @PieterGoosen

Comment: @birgire it does seem so :-). I hope everyone found this usefull in the near future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two title tags can be explained as that you are using a theme that is written for Wordpress4.1 and actually is using 4.1. As from 4.1 you don't need to call [`wp_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title) in the head any more, you can make use of new `title_tag` theme support tag which automatically adds the `wp_title()` tag in the header

The parent theme you are using are most probably already doing this. Look in your functions.php for this line of code

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

As a solution, copy the parent theme `header.php` to your child theme and simply remove the `wp_title()` function from the child theme `header.php`

Here is also a great function to keep in mind for backwards compatibility and is useful for parent theme developers: (*Taken from the codex*)

```
 if ( ! function_exists( '_wp_render_title_tag' ) ) {
    function theme_slug_render_title() 
    {
        ?>
        <title>
            <?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?>
        </title>
        <?php
    }
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_slug_render_title' );
}
```

Answer (score -3):

At `function.php` file in your theme comment code

```
//add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

Comment: This is completely wrong and will never work