# Post title appears twice in browser title bar

Tags: html

My post title appears twice on the browser title bar.
Please see this as an example: https://www.notionbug.com/newly-found-planet-just-right-life/

I've tried deacivating plugins but didn't worked.
I've also tried clearing the cache, still no success.

Answer (score 0):

check [Two title tags in my header](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181934/two-title-tags-in-my-header)

there is already add_theme_support( 'title-tag' ); in functions.php file.

the wp_title() tag in the header is automatically added.copy your parent theme header.php to your child theme and delete the wp_title() tag in the header.php

Answer (score 0):

I've just answered my own question.

- In your editor section, click on Theme Functions (`functions.php`)
- Ctrl+f and find `add_filter`
- Ctrl+f and find add_filter You’ll get something like this:
      `add_filter(‘wp_title’, ‘some_function_name’ );`
- Remove this line and update the file